# How does QTP click if no coordinates are specified?

Tags: cursor, qtp, cursor-position

I am working on a WPF & .Net application that has many WPFbuttons that I must click. When I attempt to click the button objects, sometimes it works right away, more often it waits several seconds then proceeds, and sometimes it waits up to 3 minutes before my application proceeds.

There is a workaround (or rather, a kludge) by specifying `object.Click 5,5` thereby setting QTP to click 5 pixel in from the top-left corner. This works, but why doesn't a *regular* click work on the program?
Further investigating, QTP says that by default `micNoCoordinate` is used when no coordinates are specified (this is supposed to click the center of the object).

I have tried `micNoCoordinate` as well as `5,5` and even `0,0` and while `micNoCoordinate` is a bit slower than specifying a real coordinate, all of these methods work much, much faster than not specifying a coordinate at all.

What is really going on when QTP "clicks" an object? I don't see a cursor on the button during a plain click event. Why is a plain `.Click` event so different than specifying a coordinate or even just using `micNoCoordinate`??

**EDIT:** Specifically, I'm quite interested in how the click events themselves differ when using coordinates vs. when not using coordinates. What type of click event is being simulated in each scenario?

Comment: My guess: `micNoCoordinate` clicks on the middle of the button, so it calculates (x_pos + 1/2 * width, y_pos + 1/2 * heigth) where it has to retrieve the dimensional properties of the button. This consumes more time than simple (0, 0). When you don't use an argument, the OnClick event is fired against the button. When using an argument like micNoCoordinate a real click is simulated. Firing the event is seems to be more costly. (disclaimer: this is an educated guess).

Comment: I think you're on to something. Could you tell me more about the OnClick event vs the Real Click?? (I don't see any way to specify what kind of click to send the button or any type of 'FireEvent' action.)

Comment: A Real Click is clicking a button like a user does: The mouse cursor is moved by the Windows API to the correct screen location by sending WM_MOVE messages to the application. Then a WM_LBUTTONDOWN and a WM_LBUTTONUP is send. The `onclick` event is the event that is fired from the object that received those messages to the application and can be triggerd by calling the onclick method on that object. QTP is able to perform both clicks. Which one can be set from the Tools menu and is a setting in the Options dialog (I do not have QTP installed here, so the naming can be incorrect).

Answer (score 0):

By default, if no X/Y coordinates are provided, the object's `.Click` method will click directly in the center of the object. This is the same as specifying "micNoCoordinate" for both coordinates. You have correctly identified the functionality.

Make sure you have all of the latest patches relating to .NET and WPF (QTPNET_00062 and possibly others).

Comment: I've got these QTP WPF patches installed: QTPNET_00062, 73, 81, 82, 96, 99, 106, 109, 120.

As for the clicking, I only notice a visible Windows cursor over the button if I either specify the coordinates or use `micNoCoordinate`. If I go with a plain old `.Click`, then I don't see the actual Windows cursor and the button doesn't really know it's been clicked (at least until it sobers up a minute or two later). Does QTP fire different _types_ of click events depending on the parameters?